# App Engine sample fails "AttributeError: 'AppInfoExternal' object has no attribute 'main'"

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

I installed Standard App Engine GAE for Python 2.7 v1.9.83 on Windows 10

Using Google App Engine Launcher I `File/Create New Application` and called it engineapp

From a cmd line:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py" engineapp
```

but AppEngines fails to launch the app, reporting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 96, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 90, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 600, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 588, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 266, in start
    env_variables=parsed_env_variables)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\application_configuration.py", line 966, in __init__
    env_variables)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\application_configuration.py", line 154, in __init__
    self._main = self._app_info_external.main
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\validation.py", line 352, in __getattribute__
    Raises:
AttributeError: 'AppInfoExternal' object has no attribute 'main'
```

The AppEngine installer did add its path to `Path`. `PYTHONHOME` & `PYTHONPATH` are correctly set and, from a cmd line `python --version` reports `Python 2.7.11`

Do I need to manually add any other configuration or path?

Here is my .yaml file:

```
application: engineapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

The auto-generated main.py is:

```
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello world!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Comment: You should pass the app's .yaml file as argument instead of engineapp.

Comment: thanks @DanCornilescu. I tried that but I get the same AttributeError. I tried running the cmd in the parent directory and in the same app's directory but got the same error.

Comment: Show your `.yaml` file and snippet of code setting up your main app.

Comment: thanks @DanCornilescu I've added the file contents to my question

Comment: You have `script: gaehandler.wsgiapp` in there, meaning you should have a file named `gaehandler.py` (side by side with your `app.yaml` file) in which a `wsgiapp` variable is defined. Can you show that snippet?

Comment: sorry @DanCornilescu! That was my project yaml. I've edited my question to include the example yaml that the AppEngine Launcher Create Application process generates. This removes any chance it's the framework I use from the problem set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189162/discussion-between-dan-cornilescu-and-carl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite "over installing" different versions of App Engine the solution was to deinstall first.

Once I did that, the problem went away in all versions of App Engine.